# Why cant 'Sharp' points be differentiated by Fourier Series?

Tags: calculus

While learning Fourier Series, I encountered a doubt regarding the derivates of sharp points. For instance,
consider the function f(x)=|sinx|
Its Fourier transform is
[Fourier transform of abs(sin(x))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSX30.png)
My question regarding this is why cant we derivate this function and substitute the value (for e.g., x=0) to equate slope=0? This would be more intuitive (even though it *is* wrong) as it would follow Intermediate Value theorem.

Comment: Because neither the function nor its transform is differentiable.

Comment: Unfortunately, a function is not always equal to its Fourier series. You probably want to read more about weak formulation. To summarise, instead of them being equal, their projections to a subspace of sinusoidal function space are equal. Remember, Fourier series is an APPROXIMATION

Comment: There are different notions of convergence, please check this (examples: "Uniform convergence", "Pointwise convergence", etc.). 

Consider this video for a bit more understanding of Fourier series and transform and its application: https://youtu.be/_eq8rUr1QIg  it also provides a link to a book that covers Fourier series in quite detail.